# Excel two average formulas in one cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I tried to find a solution for the following:

I have one row with five different cells.

For example:

cell 1 1:41:02

cell 2 1:42:00

cell 3 1:42:06

cell 4  1:41:06

cell 5 to calculate the average

The thing that I want is this. In last cell (cell 5) calculate the average times like:

Average(cell1, cell2) "some text" Average(cell3, cell4).

I've tried the following formulas:

= CONCATENATE(AVERAGE(C23;D23); " | "; AVERAGE(E23:F23))

= AVERAGE(C23;D23) & " | " & AVERAGE(E23:F23))

But on both of them I get weird times, well not even times but numbers.

0,0704976851851852 | 0,0705555555555556

Instead of what I want

1:41:34 | 1:41:36

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AVERAGE` is returning a number. Use the `TEXT` function

```
=TEXT(AVERAGE(),"h:mm:ss")
```

Your local settings require that you use a semi-colon rather than a comma

```
=TEXT(AVERAGE(C23;D23);"h:mm:ss")&" | "&TEXT(AVERAGE(E23;F23);"h:mm:ss")
=CONCATENATE(TEXT(AVERAGE(C23;D23);"h:mm:ss");" | ";TEXT(AVERAGE(E23;F23);"h:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: I just updated quickly for your local settings. If that solves it for you please mark the answer as accepted

Comment: It worked! Thank you but can you please explain why the CONCATENATE didn't work and the TEXT function does. I like to understand it.

Comment: Do both formulas in my answer work? If so you can compare yours to them.

Comment: Ah wait sorry, didn't look properly it makes sense now thanks!